# Cannot get original return value of promisified function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, asynchronous, promise

The code below works, but it is not promisified.

```
const express = require('express');
function listenAndReturnServer() {
    app = express();

    console.log('Before listen');
    const server = app.listen(8001, function() {
        console.log('Now listening');
    });
    console.log('After listen');
    return server;
}
const server = listenAndReturnServer();
console.log('Doing some stuff');
console.log(typeof(server));
```

It outputs the following:

```
Before listen
After listen
Doing some stuff
object
Now listening
```

The problem I am trying to solve is that I want to replace the 'Do some stuff' log with code that depends on the server running, and the listen callback (which prints 'Now listening') having been called. As you can see 'Do some stuff' is logged before 'Now listening'. In comes util.promisify.

I have changed the above to the following.

```
const express = require('express');
const util = require('util');
async function listenAndReturnServer() {
    app = express();

    console.log('Before listen');
    const listenAsync = util.promisify(app.listen);
    const server = await listenAsync(8001).then(() => {
        console.log('Now listening');
    });
    console.log('After listen');
    return server;
}
async function main() {
    const server = await listenAndReturnServer();
    console.log('Doing some stuff');
    console.log(typeof(server));
}
main();
```

And this time, things at least log in the correct order.

```
Before listen
Now listening
After listen
undefined
Doing some stuff
```

There is a new problem now: `server`'s type is undefined. I actually need it to be the original Server object, so I can close the server.

Can anyone identify what is happening here, and how I can get the behavior I want?

Comment: what's the returned value of the function here? `.then(() => { console.log('Now listening'); });` That's what the Promise will resolve to; that's what will be assigned to `const server`

Comment: I see. I am new to promises so this may explain the entirety of my issue. As you can see there is no return value. How would I get the return value of the original app.listen within the context of the unnamed function in the code snippet you posted? Is this a parameter passed to then()?

Comment: One way would be `.then((value) => { console.log('Now listening'); return value });`. Some Promise libraries provide a function to hook into the promise chain without interrupting/changing it, like [Bluebird#tap()](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/tap.html). But imo. you've already got the best answer from broofa down below, for this case.

Comment: @Thomas I tried that and `value` is undefined.

Comment: this sounds like something is going wrong here: `util.promisify(app.listen)`; the fact that the code in the answer seems to have the same problem just encourages this assumption. My best guess would be that `this` is gone, but I don't have the time to check that right now. Try `util.promisify(app.listen.bind(app))` OR `await listenAsync.call(app, 8001)` (not together)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Rewriting because there are multiple things going on here]

After working on this code for a bit, I realized there were several issues/erroneous assumptions, as follows:

```
const express = require('express');
const util = require('util');
async function listenAndReturnServer() {
    app = express();

    console.log('Before listen');

// ISSUE #1: `listenAsync` is not bound to `app` here.  This
// risks errors where Express may rely on `this` internally.
//
// ISSUE #2: Promisify is intended to operate on methods that
// take node-style callbacks, where the *callback* receives
// (err, arg0, arg1, ...) arguments, with the promise
// resolving to the 2nd argument (arg0).
// In the case of listen(), though, the callback isn't expected
// to be node-style(!), so doesn't receive any arguments
// (see https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_server_listen)
    const listenAsync = util.promisify(app.listen);

// ISSUE #3: `await` and `then()` serve similar purposes.
// Using them together like this is a little weird.
// You should probably just `await`, then do your console.log
// afterwards.      
    const server = await listenAsync(8001).then(() => {
        console.log('Now listening');
    });
    console.log('After listen');
    return server;
}
async function main() {
    const server = await listenAndReturnServer();
    console.log('Doing some stuff');
    console.log(typeof(server));
}
main();
```

If you want to Promisify this to make it work with `async`, then it's probably simpler to just create a `Promise` thusly:

```
const express = require('express');

const app = express();

// Note: Not writing this as an `async` function because none
// of the APIs we're using return promises that can be `await`ed,
// and we explicitly return a promise
function main() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    // Resolve to the server instance if listen() succeeds
    // Note: `server` here is Node's `http` server, not the Express instance
    const server = app.listen(8001, () => resolve(server));

    // Otherwise reject promise if there's an error
    server.on('error', reject);
  });
}

main()
  .then(server => console.log(server))
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Comment: I still have an issue, which is that in the solution you posted `server` is not defined.

Comment: Ignore what I wrote previously.  Updated answer with code and comments based on, you know, actually testing the code I wrote. :-p